# Meteor JS backend vs Express JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, meteor, mongoose

This is pretty much what I understood but I would like to hear more:

I read this somewhere on stack overflow, comparing meteor js and express js is like comparing oranges and potatoes. To summarize my understanding Meteor JS - full stack (Front End, Back End)
Express JS - only back end

Now I'm curious compare Meteor JS back end and Express JS (pretty much comparing varieties of potato).

Can I do everything I do in Express JS in Meteor JS backend ?
What's the advantage of Express JS over Meteor JS backend?

Is it worthy to grab data from express and display in meteor front end or just do all in meteor?

So overall my question is if express powerful to meteor js backend? What is not possible doing in Meteor backend that can be done in express?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of May 2017, I don't think anyone would choose Meteor's front-end (which is called Blaze) over the existing front end frameworks.

Meteor's backend, however, does seem to be more popular now with React as its front end. See Udemy for some fine courses on the subject.

Can Meteor do everything Express can?

Don't know. It can accept middleware, and do redirections, if that's what you're wondering.

What can Meteor do that Express can't do (easily)?

Meteor has MongoDB built-in, so you don't have to do your own mongoDB setup.

It talks to the front end using sockets, so if you want live updates of your data, you don't have to set up sockets yourself. When the database changes, your front end responds automatically - like a chat app.

Finally, it has a built-in authentication system, which saves you hours of time vs building your own login system in Express using passport or jwt, etc...